# JAX-RS POST api throws 405 method not allowed

Tags: java, http, jax-rs

I am creating a REST API using JAX-RS, and all the GET APIs work perfectly fine.  When creating a POST API, it always fails with a `405 Method not allowed` error.

##### The REST API

```java
@POST
@Path("/auditEvent")
@Operation(
    summary = "Create AuditEvent in App from snow",
    description = "Create AuditEvent in app from snow",
    responses = {
        @ApiResponse(
            description = "Response with 200 if event was created, or error message if not",
            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = AuditEvent.class))
        )
    },
    requestBody = @RequestBody(
        required = true,
        description = "Request contains all params needed to log: user, action(approve or reject), req number, reason",                        
        content = @Content(
            schema = @Schema(implementation = AuditEvent.class)
        )
    )
)
@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public String logAuditEvent(AuditEvent[] auditEvents) throws GeneralException {
    // logic to save event in database

    return "Audit event recorded successfully in App";
}
```

##### Audit Event Class

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.Map;
    
@XmlRootElement(name = "AuditEvent")
public class AuditEvent {
    public String action;
    public String eventInterface;
    public String serverHost;
    public String clientHost;
    public String source;
    public String target;
    public String application;
    public String instance;
    public Map<String, Object> attributes;
    public String attributeName;
    public String attributeValue;
}
```

##### Console Error

> ```
> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [JAX-RS REST Servlet] in context
> with path [/build] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException:
> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
> Resource Java method invocation error.] with root cause
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ```

However when I change the POST method signature to receive `map` instead of `AuditEvent` object like:

```java
public String logAuditEvent(Map<String, String> params) throws GeneralException
```

... the API started working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're getting might be related to the deserialization of the request body into the `AuditEvent` object, so I suggest to ensure that `AuditEvent` has:

- getters/setters
- default constructor
- annotations -  you're using `@XmlRootElement`, but JAX-RS may use Jackson for JSON deserialization, so you need `@JsonProperty` on your fields

Comment: I solved a half problem 
method signature need to updated from AuditEvent[] to List<AuditEvent> 

public String logAuditEvent(AuditEvent[] auditEvents) ------> public String logAuditEvent(List<AuditEvent> auditEvents) 

however it falls to another problem the JSON payload not getting mapped to AUditEvent class instead I have received a Liat of HashMap in logAuditEvent method